# I want to add a pop up confirmation when user clicks add to cart on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Basically I want to show a pop up confirmation when user clicks on Add to Cart Button on single product page. The popup will show only if the product is low on stock. It is to notify user that the product can be back ordered and it will take 2-3 weeks to be available. If user clicks on the Continue button in the popup then the product should be added to cart.

I tried this code below and its not working:

```
function add_the_validation( $passed ) {
    if ( $product->managing_stock()) {

        $currentStockQuantity  = $product->get_stock_quantity(); 
        $minStockLevel =    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'minimum_stock_level', true );

        if( ! empty( $minStockLevel ) ) {

            if($currentStockQuantity < $minStockLevel)
            {
                wc_add_notice( __( ' <div id="stock-popup" class="my-overlay">
                    <div class="my-popup" >
                        <a class="close" href="#stock-popup">×</a>
                        <div class="content">
                            Currently it is out of stock. If you want to order this product we will restore within 7 to 15days. If YES please continue Add to Cart.<br>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                             <input class="popup-button" type="submit" value="1" name="continue_add_to_cart">
                             <input class="popup-button" type="submit" value="1" name="cancel">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            }
        }

    }
    return $passed;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'add_the_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Where is your code? what have you try?

Comment: Updated the post with code I have tried. But its not working.

Comment: if you want a popup for confirmation then you should do it via Javascript. Check confirmation alert in JS

Comment: @Rajnish Any helpfull resource would be appreciated.

Comment: What i am trying to say is, 
Use JS Pop up for the confirmation, if user responds with "Yes/Ok", then add an ajax / redirect code to add the item in the cart.

Eg:
<script>
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    //add the item to the cart
} else {
    //do nothing
}
</script>

Comment: Hi @Rajnish Thanks for your comments. I like to have the confirmation popup only for those product which are low on stock. I have a custom product field $minStockLevel =    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'minimum_stock_level', true ); and the logic is $currentStockQuantity < $minStockLevel

Comment: Well you can do it this way :
<button <?php if($currentStockQuantity < $minStockLevel) echo "onclick= 'show_confirm_dialog()' "; ?> >Add to cart</button>

and write the above code in show_confirm_dialog() js function
.
.
.
or on click of every button write an ajax to check if the stocks are less or not. then move forward from there